# I need help figuring out the direction of reaction forces between the two blocks and drawing the FBD

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, free-body-diagram

The problem is as follows -
[image]

Two blocks A and B each of mass $m$ are placed on a smooth horizontal surface. Two horizontal forces $F$ and $2F$ are applied on both the blocks $A$ and $B$ respectively. as shown in the figure. The block A does not slide on block B. Then the normal reacton acting between the two blocks is

1. $F$
2. $F/2$
3. $F/ \sqrt 3$
4. $2F$

Answer : 2$F$

I am confused if the normal reaction force will be along the direction of the external force applied or will it be perpendicular to the inclined surface.